# Signalr servicebus backplane issue

Tags: angularjs, signalr-backplane

I am getting a problem in service bus, it sometimes call client method and sometimes breaks.

Here is my scenario-

when courier place a bid for customer then it calls a server side method, after calling successfully it redirect to client function via signalR, and refresh the page and get new information(using toaster).

Here is the complete code-

*Server side call

```
private Notify(ExtraLargeRequest request){

--  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NewBidHub>().Clients.All

                .broadcastBidNotification(request.Customer.Email, request.Id, "test message");

}
```

*NewBidHub.cs

```
public class NewBidHub : Hub

{

    public void SendBidNotification(string user, int requestId, string message)

    {

        // Call the method to notifiy clients.

        Clients.All.broadcastBidNotification(user, requestId, message);

    }

}
```

*client side call

```
function createNewBidHub(){

    //declaring the hub connection

    newBidHub = new Hub('newBidHub', {

        //client side methods

        listeners: {

            'broadcastBidNotification': function (customer, requestId, notification) {

                $rootScope.$broadcast('incomingBidNotification', customer, requestId, notification);

            }

        },

        methods: ['SendBidNotification'],

        //specify a non default root

        rootPath: config.baseServiceName + 'signalr'

    });

}



$rootScope.$on('incomingBidNotification', function (fn, customer, requestId, notification) {

toaster.pop("success", "New bid", notification, 5000, 'trustedHtml', onBidNotificationClick, requestId);

if ($location.path().indexOf('/requests/detail') !== -1) {

                $rootScope.$broadcast("updateRequestDetails", requestId);

            }

});
```

*Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)

    {

        GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);

        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBusConnectionString");

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connectionString, "webnotifications-ns");

        app.MapSignalR();            

    }
```

*version

ServiceBus - 2.1.0.0

jquery-signalR - 2.1.2

Could you please help me out! It would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.